# How do I change the python version in Microsoft Azure Machine Learning Notebooks?

Tags: python, tensorflow, azure-machine-learning-service

How can I change the version of Python and Tensorflow? I could not find a section in the interface or settings here that I can change. I tried to change it via console but was not successful. What is your suggestion?
[Python and Tensorflow version in Microsoft Azure Machine Learning(Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiPTB.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could connect to the terminal and upgrade the package :

[image]

I connected to the terminal and ran the below command :

[image]

```
conda update --all
```

[image]

Similary, for tensor flow

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

[image]

Post the upgrade :

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I solved the problem by creating up environment. 
Ref : https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-create-virtual-environments-in-azure-ml-workspace-in-azure-portal-39245a34b370